# YAML parsing error on unknown file of Sidekiq container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, yaml, mongoid, sidekiq

I am having trouble when i try to run this **Sidekiq service** on a docker container. My project is based on Ruby on Rails, and besides Sidekiq, it goes along with **Mongoid**, **Redis**, and the **Rails REST API** i've built.

All other services go up, but this one (actuator-controller-sidekiq) breaks with the stack below. I already checked ALL of the .yml files of the project for whitespaces, bad identation and everything else, but i can't even understand where exactly is the problem when i read this stack. Can someone help?

Im not sure which of the files from my project are relevant to put here, so if you guys could comment them, i will be editing the question with the requested files.

```
(<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 8 column 11
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:402:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:402:in `parse_stream'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:350:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:263:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongoid-6.1.1/lib/mongoid/config/environment.rb:40:in `load_yaml'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongoid-6.1.1/lib/mongoid/config.rb:86:in `load!'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongoid-6.1.1/lib/mongoid.rb:104:in `load!'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/mongoid-6.1.1/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:59:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/rafael/git/tcc/interscity-dev/actuator-controller/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:255:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:255:in `boot_system'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:54:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-5.0.0/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the problem =)

The environment variables to the Mongoid host/port were not in the Sidekiq vars on the docker-compose file. Added them and now it works!